# Android: SQLite error in adding data

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I'm working on a PiggyBank-like application wherein users can make wishlists of their wanted item and helps them save for that item. My app is still in prototype because i'm still learning android.

The problem i'm experiencing right now is every time i add a new data, it always returns false. Here's my code:

**DatabaseHelper.java**

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;


public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String TAG = "DatabaseHelper";

private static final String TABLE_NAME = "people_table";
private static final String COL1 = "ID";
private static final String COL2 = "name";
private static final String COL3 = "price";
private static final String COL4 = "totalsavings";
private static final String COL5 = "duedate";


public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, TABLE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COL2 +" TEXT, " + COL3 + "TEXT, " + COL4 +"INTEGER)";
    db.execSQL(createTable);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
    db.execSQL("DROP IF TABLE EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

public boolean addData(String item) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL2, item);
    contentValues.put(COL3, item);
    contentValues.put(COL4, item);

    Log.d(TAG, "addData: Adding " + item + " to " + TABLE_NAME);

    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

    //if date as inserted incorrectly it will return -1
    if (result == -1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

/**
 * Returns all the data from database
 * @return
 */
public Cursor getData(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
    Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    return data;
}

/**
 * Returns only the ID that matches the name passed in
 * @param name
 * @return
 */
public Cursor getItemID(String name){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT " + COL1 + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME +
            " WHERE " + COL2 + " = '" + name + "'";
    Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    return data;
}

/**
 * Updates the name field
 * @param newName
 * @param id
 * @param oldName
 */
public void updateName(String newName, int id, String oldName){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "UPDATE " + TABLE_NAME + " SET " + COL2 +
            " = '" + newName + "' WHERE " + COL1 + " = '" + id + "'" +
            " AND " + COL2 + " = '" + oldName + "'";
    Log.d(TAG, "updateName: query: " + query);
    Log.d(TAG, "updateName: Setting name to " + newName);
    db.execSQL(query);
}

/**
 * Delete from database
 * @param id
 * @param name
 */
public void deleteName(int id, String name){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE "
            + COL1 + " = '" + id + "'" +
            " AND " + COL2 + " = '" + name + "'";
    Log.d(TAG, "deleteName: query: " + query);
    Log.d(TAG, "deleteName: Deleting " + name + " from database.");
    db.execSQL(query);
}

}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper;
private Button btnAdd, btnViewData;
private EditText editText, editText2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //for inputs
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    editText2 =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    //buttons
    btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    btnViewData = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnView);

    //call database
    mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String newEntry = editText.getText().toString();
            if (editText.length() != 0) {
                AddData(newEntry);
                editText.setText("");
            } else {
                toastMessage("You must put something in the text field!");
            }

            String newPriceEntry = editText2.getText().toString();
            if (editText2.length() != 0) {
                AddData(newPriceEntry);
                editText2.setText("");
            } else {
                toastMessage("You must put something in the text field!");
            }

        }
    });

    btnViewData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListDataActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}

public void AddData(String newEntry) {
    boolean insertData = mDatabaseHelper.addData(newEntry);

    if (insertData) {
        toastMessage("Data Successfully Inserted!");
    } else {
        toastMessage("Something went wrong");
    }
}

/**
 * customizable toast
 * @param message
 */
private void toastMessage(String message){
    Toast.makeText(this,message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

**ListDataActivity.java**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
* Created by User on 2/28/2017.
*/

public class ListDataActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "ListDataActivity";

DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper;

private ListView mListView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_layout);
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    populateListView();
}

private void populateListView() {
    Log.d(TAG, "populateListView: Displaying data in the ListView.");

    //get the data and append to a list
    Cursor data = mDatabaseHelper.getData();
    ArrayList<String> listData = new ArrayList<>();
    while(data.moveToNext()){
        //get the value from the database in column 1
        //then add it to the ArrayList
        listData.add(data.getString(1));

    }
    //create the list adapter and set the adapter
    ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listData);
    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    //set an onItemClickListener to the ListView
    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            String name = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
            Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: You Clicked on " + name);

            Cursor data = mDatabaseHelper.getItemID(name); //get the id associated with that name
            int itemID = -1;
            while(data.moveToNext()){
                itemID = data.getInt(0);
            }
            if(itemID > -1){
                Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: The ID is: " + itemID);
                Intent editScreenIntent = new Intent(ListDataActivity.this, EditDataActivity.class);
                editScreenIntent.putExtra("id",itemID);
                editScreenIntent.putExtra("name",name);
                startActivity(editScreenIntent);
            }
            else{
                toastMessage("No ID associated with that name");
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * customizable toast
 * @param message
 */
private void toastMessage(String message){
    Toast.makeText(this,message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
}
```

**EditDataActivity.java**
In this activity, the data will be displayed in an EditText (name), the savings goal (price). (I'm still working on the totalsavings).

```
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;



 public class EditDataActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "EditDataActivity";

private TextView myGoal, mySavings;
private Button btnSave,btnDelete, btnDeposit;
private EditText editable_item, depositInput;

DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper;

private String selectedName, selectedPrice;
private int selectedID, selectedTotalSavings;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.edit_data_layout);

    myGoal =  (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayGoal);
    mySavings = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayTotalSavings);

    btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
    btnDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);
    btnDeposit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDeposit);

    editable_item = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editable_item);
    mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    //get the intent extra from the ListDataActivity
    Intent receivedIntent = getIntent();

    //now get the itemID we passed as an extra
    selectedID = receivedIntent.getIntExtra("id",-1); //NOTE: -1 is just the default value

    //now get the name we passed as an extra
    selectedName = receivedIntent.getStringExtra("name");

    //now get the price we passed as an extra
    selectedPrice = receivedIntent.getStringExtra("price");

    //now we get the totalsavings we passed as an extra
    selectedTotalSavings = receivedIntent.getIntExtra("totalsavings", -1);

    //set the text to show the current selected name
    editable_item.setText(selectedName);

    //set the text to show the user's saving goal
    myGoal.setText(selectedPrice);

    //set text to show the user's total savings so far
    mySavings.setText(selectedTotalSavings);

        //-----------------------------------DIALOG BOX-----------------------------------------
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Enter Deposit");
        builder.setMessage("Enter your deposit!");

        depositInput= new EditText(this);
        builder.setView(depositInput);

            //SET POSITIVE BUTTON
                builder.setPositiveButton("Submit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        String depositTxt=depositInput.getText().toString();

                        selectedTotalSavings = Integer.parseInt(selectedTotalSavings + depositTxt);
                        mySavings.setText(selectedTotalSavings);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),depositTxt, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

            //SET NEGATIVE BUTTON
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

            //CREATE THE DIALOG
            final AlertDialog depositPrompt=builder.create();

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    //buttons
    btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String item = editable_item.getText().toString();
            if(!item.equals("")){
                mDatabaseHelper.updateName(item,selectedID,selectedName);
            }else{
                toastMessage("You must enter a name");
            }
        }
    });

    btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mDatabaseHelper.deleteName(selectedID,selectedName);
            editable_item.setText("");
            toastMessage("removed from database");
        }
    });

    btnDeposit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0){
            depositPrompt.show();


        }
    });

}

/**
 * customizable toast
 * @param message
 */
private void toastMessage(String message){
    Toast.makeText(this,message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
}
```

**Here's the Sample Syntax**

- User enters details for name and price
- User clicks add data
- User can View Data and the data will be displayed on a ListView
- User can edit and view data in the EditDataActivity

I'm not sure what the problem is.

**UPDATE**

so i found this code on the MainActivity Class. I'm trying to add the data from editText2 but i don't know how.

```
 btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String newEntry = editText.getText().toString();
            if (editText.length() != 0) {
                AddData(newEntry);
                editText.setText("");
            } else {
                toastMessage("You must put something in the text field!");
            }

            String newPriceEntry = editText2.getText().toString();
            if (editText2.length() != 0) {
                AddData(newPriceEntry);
                editText2.setText("");
            } else {
                toastMessage("You must put something in the text field!");
            }

        }
    });

    btnViewData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListDataActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}

public void AddData(String newEntry) {
    boolean insertData = mDatabaseHelper.addData(newEntry);

    if (insertData) {
        toastMessage("Data Successfully Inserted!");
    } else {
        toastMessage("Something went wrong");
    }
}
```

Do i have to make a new AddData?

Comment: use ormlite rather than sqlite for fast operation

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert the right type of values as mentioned below :

```
public boolean addData(String item) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL2, item);
    contentValues.put(COL3, item);
    contentValues.put(COL4, item); // pass an integer instead of a String as you have mentioned its datatype as INTEGER or parse it using Integer.parseInt()

    Log.d(TAG, "addData: Adding " + item + " to " + TABLE_NAME);

    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

    //if date as inserted incorrectly it will return -1
    if (result == -1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually according to [this](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html). *"In SQLite, the datatype of a value is associated with the value itself, not with its container. "*

Answer (score 0):

The problem I think is in the `CREATE TABLE` query.

```
String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COL2 +" TEXT, " + COL3 + "TEXT, " + COL4 +"INTEGER)";
```

There is no space between `COL3` and `"TEXT"` (same for `COL4` and `"INTEGER"`). So just add a space like so.

```
String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COL2 +" TEXT, " + COL3 + " TEXT, " + COL4 +" INTEGER)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in your `addData()` method. `COL4` holds `INTEGER` value.

**Try this:**

```
public boolean addData(String item) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL2, item);
    contentValues.put(COL3, item);
    contentValues.put(COL4, Integer.parseInt(item));

    Log.d(TAG, "addData: Adding " + item + " to " + TABLE_NAME);

    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

    //if date as inserted incorrectly it will return -1
    if (result == -1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The return of db.insert() is a long and you're comparing it to an int. Change

```
if (result == -1) {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
```

To

```
return (int)result == -1;
```